# Spring MongoDB Repositories on multi class collections return all types not the repository one

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I would like to store some configuration related classes in the same mongo collection. Thereby I have 2 different objects.

```
@Document(Collection="config")
public class Config {...}
```

and

```
@Document(Collection="config")
public class ActiveFieldsConfig {...}
```

I use Spring MongoDB repositories to save and query them

```
public interface ConfigRepository extends MongoRepository<Config, String> {} 
public interface ActiveFieldsConfigRepository extends MongoRepository<ActiveFieldsConfig, String> {}
```

The problem I encountered is that the findAll() query will return all documents of both types and cast them to the type of the repository that invoked the query. I would like to configure both Repositories to only account their corresponding Documents for queries like findAll().

Can the repositories be configured to automatically add their _class to their queries?

Do i have to supply a completely rewritten implementation of MongoRepository?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do it that way. Another option is to have a unique field which differentiates between documents of class Config and ActiveFieldsConfig. And instead of doing findAll, do findAllByUniqueId. Or you can try out Inheritance and using `@DBRef`

Comment: Take a look at this article:
https://medium.com/@mladen.maravic/spring-data-mongodb-my-take-on-inheritance-support-102361c08e3d